# Databricks Notebook as Substitute for livy sessions endpoint

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, livy

I want to execute a Databrikcs Notebook's code via Databricks API and get the output of notebook's code as response.

Is it possible of is there any workaround for the same ?

Is the same possible with Databricks SQL api ?

Comment: You can create databricks job and run that jobs through JOB API call. ref : https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a job via UI, and then trigger it with [run-now API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow), or you can use [run-submit API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit) to create ephemeral job.  The both calls will give back the Run ID. Then you can monitor the status via [get-run API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsGet), and wait for the notebook executed.  And after that you can get output of the notebook with [get-output API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsGetOutput).

You can also execute the individual commands on the existing cluster, using the [older API 1.2](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/1.2/index.html#command-execution-1).